# How can i make basic Bet App by using Mongodb-Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, triggers

I've been developing some small applications for a while using nodejs and mongodb to improve myself in the backend area.I am currently trying to make a simple football betting application. Because instant data update, triggers etc seems like a really advanced topic. But I'm stuck on one thing.

I don't know how to make a system that will check the coupons consisting of many matches made by the user when the football matches are over and are resulted, and pay the user the money according to the winning and losing results.

What topics should I research and what kind of tutorials should I study?

(If you have a course or document to recommend, I would be glad.)

Answer (score 0):

there's sports apis that you can use, they give you live score and after game score, with status of the game so you can per exemple check on bet's last game finished if what he predicted is right etc..

here's a list of API services :

```
 API-FOOTBALL API
 Cricket Live Scores API
 API-NBA API
 The Rundown API
 Football Prediction API
 Soccer - Sports Open Data API
 Live Sports Odds API
 ElenaSport.io API
 SportsMonk Football Pro API
 SportScore API
```

Comment: Actually my question is about processing the data in the database according to the incoming data. Thanks anyway.